# How can I focus on a Button within a custom ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, focus

In my app it has a custom `ListView'`. The `ListView` contains an Image button. At the moment if the user is using an Android phone or tablet they can select and press this Button.

But if they are using for example a Firestick that uses a remote I can't select it. How can I make sure that I can scroll through my list but also make sure it scrolls through the buttons as well when using a remote?

My custom.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:id="@+id/titleapp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="@drawable/button_textcolour"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/detail"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titleapp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img"
    android:textColor="@drawable/button_textcolour"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/detail"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/downloads"
    android:id="@+id/downloadcounttext"
    android:layout_below="@+id/detail"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/detail"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:textColor="@drawable/button_textcolour"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/counterdl"
    android:layout_below="@+id/detail"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/detail"
    android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
    android:textColor="@drawable/button_textcolour"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/date_added"
    android:id="@+id/dateaddedtxt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/detail"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/detail"
    android:textColor="@drawable/button_textcolour"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text="01/01/0000"
    android:id="@+id/datetext"
    android:layout_below="@+id/detail"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dateaddedtxt"
    android:textColor="@drawable/button_textcolour"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Report?"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/report"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
//HERE I WANT THIS BUTTON ON EVERY ITEM TO BE ABLE TO GAIN FOCUS WITH IN THE LIST

<ImageButton
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/report"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_sentiment_dissatisfied_black_24dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/detail" />
```

My method in my BaseAdapter that allows selection of the button:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { final View row;

    if (convertView == null) {
        row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom, parent, false);
    } else {
        row = convertView;
    }
 report = row.findViewById(R.id.report);
    report.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            title.setText(Title[position]);
            String getappname = title.getText().toString();
            if (getappname!= null){
                Log.i("Bad App ", getappname);
```

Comment: What framework do you use to draw that XML in Java ?

Comment: for the listview?